# check row number if both object values are present in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

[image]

I am facing an issue in javascript, I want to do display `row_number` if both object values are not present in `Name` or `Mobile`.

how can i do this?

```
                    var rows = [];  //display row number
                    for(var i=0;i<XL_row_object.length;i++){
                        if(XL_row_object[i].Name !== "" &&  XL_row_object[i].Mobile !== "" ){ 
                            console.log(XL_row_object[i].__rowNum__);    
                            rows ++;    
                        }
                    }
```

console data

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Name: "Alex", Mobile: "3433095622", __rowNum__: 0}
1: {Name: "John", Mobile: "3005095622", __rowNum__: 2}
2: {Mobile: "3103695624", __rowNum__: 3}
3: {Name: "Bell", __rowNum__: 4}
4: {Name: "Robot", Mobile: "3433456622", __rowNum__: 5}
```

Expected Output:

```
__rowNum__:3
__rowNum__:4
```

what should i do? anyone help me?

Comment: you need to add `_rowNum_` to the rows I believe: `rows.push(XL_row_object[i].__rowNum__)`

Comment: yes but they show all _rowNum_ like this `(5) [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3906603/jumshud)

Comment: you can do it by `rows.push({__rowNum__: XL_row_object[i].__rowNum__})` or it would better to check my answer below

Comment: You need to update if condition as well: `if(!XL_row_object[i].Name ||  !XL_row_object[i].Mobile )`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply get it as below:

```
const rows = XL_row_object
   .filter(item => !(item.Name && item.Mobile))
   .map(item => ({__rowNum__: item.__rowNum__)});
```

if you don't need `__rowNum__` key:

```
const rows = XL_row_object
   .filter(item => !(item.Name && item.Mobile)) 
   .map(item => item.__rowNum__);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use first `filter` and then `map`.

```js
const data = [
  { Name: "Alex", Mobile: "3433095622", "__rowNum__": 0 },
  { Name: "John", Mobile: "3005095622", "__rowNum__": 2 },
  { Mobile: "3103695624", "__rowNum__": 3 },
  { Name: "Bell", "__rowNum__": 4 },
  { Name: "Robot", Mobile: "3433456622", "__rowNum__": 5 },
];

const res = data
  .filter(({ Mobile, Name }) => !(Mobile && Name))
  .map(({ __rowNum__ }) => __rowNum__);

console.log(res);
```